Are spans of time - 1990s, in my 30s - Saxon genitives
Consider these statements:

Chart listings in the year 1960 did not include Beatles songs


Fashion was influenced by the Beatles as they became popular

The first can be re-written as

1960's chart listings did not include Beatles songs

The second can be rewritten as

The Beatles influenced 1960's fashion

Both these rewrites sound like Saxon genitives to me.  How about when simply referring to a period of years.  For example:

The Beatles were big in the 1960s / 1960's ?


The remaining Beatles are in their 80s / 80's ?

I am NOT asking whether an apostrophe should be used (nor, if so, where precisely it should be located).  I am curious to understand better whether these examples are Saxon genitives - that is examples of possession or association between two nouns.  Obviously, ellipsis is understood (i.e. the noun adjunct on its own is sufficient).  So -
1960's means the years of the decade 1960-9
80's means the years of their eighth decade

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
